# Out of memory exception after adding xlarge screen support

Tags: android, performance

I have an Android app that has been live for more than 2 years.  I have diligently watched the developer console for crashes and app has never had issues.

However, in an effort to support tablets, I modified the manifest file to include support for xlarge screens. To enable this value, I also changed the targeted API level from 7 to 16.  Since releasing these changes, I see several crashes on the developer console for "out of memory".  No other code changes were made, so I'm confident the configuration change is at least indirectly responsible for the crashes.

All of the crash reports have "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" during inflation of the views as part of my app start-up.  Several users have included messages to indicate that the app is crashing during screen rotates and/or on initial start-up.  Also, the devices being used in the crash report all have xlarge screens (HTC One XL, Galaxy S4, Galaxy Note3, etc).

1) Why would changing these configurations lead to out of memory?  My app uses the same images regardless of screen size (I only have 1 set of images).  Also, several users have confirmed that old versions of the app worked fine on their devices, so I believe my app can run on the large screens with the old configuration.

2) When I try to reproduce, I can't start an emulator with 1920x1080 resolution.  I tried on my Mac and my Win-PC, but neither starts. I have 8GB of ram on both computers. Any screen size smaller starts just fine, like 1280x720 (app works fine on these screens).  Further, I tried on GenyMotion and Android SDK emulator but both fail. Short of buying one of these devices, does anybody have ideas on how to emulate large screen devices?

Comment: which drawable folder have your app images (drawable, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi...) ?

Comment: 90% of images are in drawable.  10% in drawable-land / drawable-port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawable` folder equivalent to `drawable-mdpi` folder.
devices like "one xl", "S4", "Note 3" and "Nexus5" have `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi` resolution.
mdpi = 1x, xhdpi = 2x, xxhdpi = 3x, xxxhdpi = 4x.

Now, if you have a large image(screen background) lets say with dimension 1280x720 in drawable folder, and you have run your app on device with xhdpi screen. Android system will scale that image by multiplying it with 2.
The result image will be 2560x1440 on xhdpi. and 3840x2160 on xxdpi.
As you can see those images are very large and need a huge memory size which case a `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

Im not sure why after changing you API level to 16, but i think after updating the target API, your app start supporting those screen density.

**UPDATE**
I suggest you put those images (large ones) in drawabale-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi folders. so Android system will not scale the images.

Comment: excellent suggestion.  when I solve part 2 of the question, I will test / approve answer.  I just ordered a phone off ebay, so it will take several days for me to verify.

Comment: I was able to verify the fix.  Thanks again for the help.